# How to avoid "permission denied" when copying damaged files?

Tags: vbscript

I write a VBScript to copy file from E drive to C drive. There are many system files and damaged files in E drive, so when copy these files, the script will stop. Any method to pass or skip these files when the script is running?

the code is to copy all folders from E drive to C drive

```
Const hd = "E:\"
Const cd = "C:\"

Dim path



Sub GenPath()
path = cd 

End Sub

Sub GenFolder()
Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFso.CreateFolder path
 Set objFso = Nothing

End Sub

Set fso=WScript.CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set fs=fso.GetFolder("E:\")
Set f=fs.SubFolders
For Each uu In f

            Set Ws = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")
            Ws.CopyFolder  uu,path & "\"
```

Comment: The code you posted is broken and can't possibly work. Please fix it.

Comment: If you want help with your code, **post your code** and not something you made up on the fly or typed from memory. The code you've posted won't even come close to executing (for at least the reason you have an `End If` without having an `If` to end). Posting made-up code and asking for help debugging it is a waste of both our time and yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each uu In f

       Set Ws = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")
       Ws.CopyFolder hd & uu,path1
   End If 


Next
```

Becomes
    Set Ws = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")

```
On Error Resume Next
For Each uu In f

       Ws.CopyFolder uu.path, path1
       If err.number <> 0 then err.clear

Next
```

Plus for an unknown reason you have an `End If`.

This does the basics but you can work on it to recreate the folder structure (this dumps all files in one folder).

```
On error resume next
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set f = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\David Candy\Desktop")
fso.createfolder("C:\Users\David Candy\test123")
Folder2 = "C:\Users\David Candy\test123"
For Each thing in f.subfolders
        msgbox thing.path
        If err.number <> 0 then 
            msgbox err.description
            err.clear
        End If
    For Each thingy in thing.files
        msgbox thingy.path
        thingy.copy(Folder2 & "\" & thingy.name)
        If err.number <> 0 then 
            msgbox err.description
            err.clear
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Only took an extra line and an edit on another line to recreate file structure.

```
On error resume next
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set f = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\David Candy\Desktop")
fso.createfolder("C:\Users\David Candy\test123")
Folder2 = "C:\Users\David Candy\test123"
Set log = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\logfile.txt") 
For Each thing in f.subfolders
    fso.createfolder(folder2 & "\" & thing.name)
    If err.number <> 0 then 
        log.writeline thing.path & err.description
        err.clear
    End If
    For Each thingy in thing.files
        thingy.copy(Folder2 & "\" & thing.name & "\" & thingy.name)
        If err.number <> 0 then 
            log.writeline thingy.path & err.description 
            err.clear
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: thank you very much, I tried it , and it looks good before the copy comes to the folder Documents and Settings, the folder is very complex, there are many system folders and damaged files in it, the script stopped, no error shows up, no files copy,  nothing happens, do you have any idea？ thanks again